# xpath match - find if tags with values not in set of values exists

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML

```
<Record>
   <subRecord>
      <Type>A</Type>
   </subRecord>
</Record>
<Record>
   <subRecord>
      <Type>B</Type>
   </subRecord>
</Record>
<Record>
   <subRecord>
      <Type>C</Type>
   </subRecord>
</Record>
```

I want to find if not(exists(//Record/subRecord/Type where Type not in ('A', 'B')). Typically in the above example I should get a false since there is a //record/subRecord/Type=C. Please help me with an xpath for this condition.

Answer (score 3):

While making this a valid XML snippet (root tag):

```
<Data>
    <Record>
        <subRecord>
            <Type>A</Type>
        </subRecord>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <subRecord>
            <Type>B</Type>
        </subRecord>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <subRecord>
            <Type>C</Type>
        </subRecord>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

This XPATH will return `<Type>C</Type>`:

```
Record/subRecord/Type[not(.="A" or .="B")]
```

And this XPATH will return True if there are any that are not `A` or `B`.

```
count(Record/subRecord/Type[not(.="A" or .="B")])>0
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I got the idea from your response and used not(exists(Record/subRecord/Type[not(.="A" or .="B")])) which returned false for my condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

```
not(/*/*/*/Type[not(contains('|A|B|', concat('|',.,'|')))])
```

This expression is practical to use in cases where the list/set of values against which to check is very long. It also makes it easy to pass a pipe-delimited list of values as a parameter.

**XSLT -based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "not(/*/*/*/Type[not(contains('|A|B|', concat('|',.,'|')))])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (formed by wrapping the provided fragment into a single top element):

```
<t>
    <Record>
        <subRecord>
            <Type>A</Type>
        </subRecord>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <subRecord>
            <Type>B</Type>
        </subRecord>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <subRecord>
            <Type>C</Type>
        </subRecord>
    </Record>
</t>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
false
```

**When the same transformation is applied on *this* XML document:**

```
<t>
    <Record>
        <subRecord>
            <Type>A</Type>
        </subRecord>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <subRecord>
            <Type>B</Type>
        </subRecord>
    </Record>
</t>
```

**again the correct result is produced**:

```
true
```

**Explanation**:

Direct use of the **[Double Negation Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)**.